# Teamcity nuget server with external nugets

Tags: nuget, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Can I add an arbitrary nuget (not built on teamcity) to be served from teamcity nuget server? (I'm using teamcity 8.1.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK that's currently not natively supported, but you can work around that by making a (one-time) build config that publishes the external packages you want as artifacts so they will be available from TeamCity going forward - you can even generalize that by having that build config pick up all packages in a given folder / network path.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I did :).